# Does whipping my oxen hurt them?

Tags: the-oregon-trail-40th-anniversary

When moving along the trail you can go at a slow pace or whip your oxen so that they move faster. Is that mechanic just a part of the trail-running aspect of the game, to help you dodge obstacles and such? Or is there a tradeoff for the extra speed?

So... Does whipping your oxen make them get injured more often/quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played this game, but I found [a youtube video which has your answer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MiUYu2BBgNE#t=8m52s). In it, a tip pops up on screen and says, "Up ahead are some obstacles on the road. If you hit them with your oxen or wagon, they will get harmed. **The faster you are going, the greater the damage**..." The trade off would be greater damage from obstacles. To specifically answer whether whipping oxen hurts them, **no, your oxen aren't hurt by being whipped, but the whip makes them move faster which causes them and the wagon to sustain more damage when you hit obstacles.**